# Where can I ask a question related to paper management?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am currently managing a non-profit project? I have a large amount of documents in paper format. Where can I ask a question concerning the organization of stacks of paper that seemingly "overflow". I would ask on Stack Overflow but I doubt I can go there... :P

In essence, where can I ask questions about home workspace organization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does [Personal Productivity](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/) sound right?

From their [help](https://productivity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> achieving a productivity workflow

This seems to fit if the question is about how to organize it to be productive. If the question is more software related it isn't allowed there.

Comment: *"Couldn't find productivity.stackexchange.com
The Q&A site productivity.stackexchange.com doesn't seem to exist…yet."* Are you from the future?

Comment: @JJforPopcornandMonica - Productivity.SE was shut down a while ago for inactivity and lack of moderation.